# How to enable bigger RAM capacity?

Tags: memory

I wanted to upgrade my RAM so I put 2 4GB Adata sticks, however the PC recogizes them as 2GB means I have 4GB total RAM instead of 8GB. I found out the the CPU supports up to 32GB of RAM so this shouldn't be a problem. Looks like the 2 slots I have are built only for max.2GB per slot. Where do you think the problem could be? Please, help.

Specs:
PC - Lenovo H430
CPU - Intel Celeron G530, 2400MHz

Check the screenshots:

[Chipset specs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2Iif.png)

[Memory slots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERdwA.png)

[Max RAM supported by CPU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NNBd.png)

Comment: Asked on the second screenshot you installed 2 GB DDR3 modules.

Comment: LAst time I had to upgrade memory in a laptop, I got compatible memory, but I had to contact support for a bios flash that would allow the full amount of RAM. always worth reaching out to them

Comment: Are you sure you actually installed 8GB RAM rather than 4GB RAM? Sometimes the hypothesis that makes least assumptions is correct, that in this case is you actually only installed 4GB RAM, from my own experience, typically DDR3 4GB RAM module would have 8 identical memory chips on one side of the circuit board, so that's 512MB each, DDR3 8GB module will have 8 chips on the each side so the total is 16 chips. Maybe your modules have 4 chips each, you can view amount of installed RAM in BIOS. The assumption that the two slots only allow 2GB max to be used each doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Yes I'm sure I installed 2 4GB sticks (2x4GB=8GB). Here is a link to the exact model of the memory:https://www.little-phoenix.com/en/p/4274-barrette-memoire-4go-ram-ddr3-adata-ad31600e002gmu-dimm-pc3-12800u-3665541041706.html

Comment: @XeнεiΞэnвϵς I cannot check the number of chips since they're hidden under a red cover, but I'm sure they're 4GB each.

Answer (score 0):

According to this article

[Lenove H430 memory](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/ca/en/products/desktops-and-all-in-ones/lenovo-h-series-desktops/lenovo-h430-desktop/10091/solutions/ht504725-where-to-find-the-maximum-supported-ram-information)

the maximum memory is 8 GB so 2 4 GB modules. (the memory number is in a picture - no text to post)

You would need to post the exact model number to be certain.

This Crucial selector also says 8 GB.

[Crucial Selector](https://www.crucial.com/compatible-upgrade-for/lenovo/lenovo-h430)

> Maximum memory: 8GB
>
> *Not to exceed manufacturer supported memory.
>
> Slots: 2 (2 banks of 1)
>
> Standard memory: 4GB or 8GB removable

Make sure you are using supported memory. Crucial is a good pick.

Comment: I used Adata sticks because I had some spare ones at home even tho officialy they're not supported. I just wonder if there was some software hack that would allow the PC to use all that 8GB.

Comment: You need compatible memory as I posted or you will get unpredictable results (as I think you may be seeing)

Comment: @Alex - The manufacturer doesn’t matter when it comes to memory compatibility.  It only matters what the size and frequency that of the module.  No; There isn’t a software hack.